# c++ split QWORD hex into smaller variables

Tags: c++

I have an unsigned long long, and I want to split it into smaller bytes.
e.g.

```
unsigned long long TEST = 0x465958432E1F0199;
```

I want it split into characters as follows.
`char TEST2 equal to 0x46, TEST3 equal to 0x59, TEST4 equal to 0x58`, and so on. How would I Do this?

Comment: cast its memory address to `uint_8*`?

Comment: Are you asking about mask and shift? For example `(TEST >> 4) & 0xFF;` will give you `0x19`. So your `TEST2` would be `(TEST >> 56) & 0xFF;`.

Answer (score 1):

Using pointers will do the trick.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<uint8_t> iterateOverBytes(const T& var) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> toReturn;

    for(auto i = 0u; i < sizeof(var); ++i) {
        toReturn.push_back(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&var)[i]);
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

`sizeof(var)` returns size of `var` in bytes, you can use pointer to `var` like array of bytes with size `sizeof(var)`.

Now simple loop printing numbers completes code:

```
for(const auto& byte: iterateOverBytes(TEST)) {
    std::cout << std::hex << int(byte) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a solution which requires no casts at all? (;

```
unsigned long long TEST = 0x465958432E1F0199;
uint8_t elements[sizeof(TEST)];
memcpy(elements, &test, sizeof(elements));
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading each byte of an integer value using a recast pointer is not portable, because systems can have different ways of ordering the component bytes which make up integer values.  Big-endian systems place the most siginificant byte first in memory, while little-endian systems start with the lowest-order byte.

To portably handle this, use a bit shifting operator to place the desired byte in the lowest-order position of a derived integer value, then cast the result to a byte-sized integer type (like `uint8_t`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    const unsigned long long word = 0x465958432E1F0199ull;
    // scan through all bytes, adding each one to a vector
    // most significant byte first
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes;
    for(auto i=sizeof(word)-1; i+1; --i) {
        const auto b = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(word >> i*8);
        bytes.push_back(b);
    }
    // Dump vector of bytes as 2-digit hex values
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for(auto b : bytes) {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(b) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output

`46 59 58 43 2e 1f 01 99`